# Rearrange the number in a Generic List

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, generic-list

I am not sure if the title of my question is in sync with the content of my question.

I have a dropdown list with the datasource being list `List<int>` numbers;
On a Delete button click the numbers from the dropdown get deleted and and on Add Button click numbers are added to the dropdown.

Now if have 1, 2, 3 in my dropdown and if I delete 1, I want the number 2 and 3 to be replaced by 1 and 2. I am not sure how to do this. Can someone please help me?

```
   if(!IsPostBack)
    {
     List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
            Session["data"] = numbers;
      rest of other code....
     }

   protected void btnAddDetail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numbers = (List<int>)Session["data"];
        if (numbers == null) { numbers = new List<int>(); }
        if (numbers.Count!=0)
        {
            int max = numbers.Max();
            numbers.Add(max + 1);
            drpdown1.DataSource = numbers;
            drpdown1.DataBind();
            drpdown1.SelectedValue = numbers.Max().ToString();
            Session["data"] = numbers;

        }
       }
     protected void btnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       numbers = (List<int>)Session["data"];
        int detailIndex = numbers.FindIndex(c => c == Convert.ToInt32      (deleteNo));
        numbers.RemoveAt(detailIndex);
        drpdown1.DataSource = numbers;
        drpdown1.DataBind();
         Session["data"] = numbers;
       }
```

Now when I rebind the dropdown list I want the numbers 2 and 3 to be replaced by 1 and 2.

Comment: What type of object is a List number?

Comment: can you modify the list, remove 3 and rebind the drop down list?

Comment: You want all the numbers to shift up when a lower number is deleted?  Will there ever be any gaps in the number sequence?  Not sure I understand whats going on...

Comment: If you have "1 2 3" in your list, and you delete "2" the your list will have a "1 2", but it won't held a "1 ? 2" structure. A List<int> can't keep empty elements. First you have a list of three elements, and after you remove one (any one) you have a list with two items. If you need to keep the indexes you would have to apply a different approach. If not, just eliminate the highest number, right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, try using an index array:

put these two controls in the aspx page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNumbers" runat="server" />
<asp:Button id="btnRemove" runat="server" />
```

put this code in your code-behind:

```
public ArrayList  Numbers
{
    get
    {
        return (ArrayList)this.ViewState["Numbers"];
    }
    set
    {
        this.ViewState["Numbers"] = value;
    }
}

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    this.btnRemove.Click += new EventHandler(btnRemove_Click);
    base.OnInit(e);
}

void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Numbers.RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt32(this.ddlNumbers.SelectedValue));
    this.BindList();
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.Numbers = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            this.Numbers.Add(i);
        }
        this.BindList();
    }
}

private void BindList()
{
    this.ddlNumbers.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.Numbers.Count; i++)
    {
        this.ddlNumbers.Items.Add((i + 1).ToString());
    }
}
```